# Plotting three-dimensional plot with Interpolating functions

Tags: plotting, animation

I want to plot my functions, but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong.
I want to be able to animate it as well.

```
N0 = 4; μ = 2; ϵ = 5
crazy = Flatten[
Join[
Table[x[i, j]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[i, j][t]^2)*x[i, j]'[t] - 
  x[i, j][t] + μ*(x[i + 1, j][t] + x[i, j + 1][t] - 
     4*x[i, j][t] + x[i - 1, j][t] + x[i, j - 1][t]), {i, 1, 
 N0 - 1}, {j, 1, N0 - 1}],

{Table[
 x[i, 0]''[t] == -x[i, 0][t] + ϵ*(1 - x[i, 0][t]^2)*
    x[i, 0]'[
     t] + μ*(x[i, 1][t] + x[i + 1, 0][t] - 4*x[i, 0][t] + 
      x[i - 1, 0][t] + x[i, N0][t]), {i, 1, N0 - 1}],

Table[
 x[i, N0]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[i, N0][t]^2)*x[i, N0]'[t] - 
   x[i, N0][
    t] + μ*(x[i + 1, N0][t] + x[i, 0][t] - 4*x[i, N0][t] + 
      x[i - 1, N0][t] + x[i, N0 - 1][t]), {i, 1, N0 - 1}],

Table[
 x[0, j]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[0, j][t]^2)*x[0, j]'[t] - 
   x[0, j][t] + μ*(x[1, j][t] + x[0, j + 1][t] - 
      4*x[0, j][t] + x[N0, j][t] + x[0, j - 1][t]), {j, 1, 
  N0 - 1}],

Table[
 x[N0, j]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[N0, j][t]^2)*x[N0, j]'[t] - 
   x[N0, j][
    t] + μ*(x[0, j][t] + x[N0, j + 1][t] - 4*x[N0, j][t] + 
      x[N0 - 1, j][t] + x[N0, j - 1][t]), {j, 1, N0 - 1}],

x[0, 0]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[0, 0][t]^2)*x[0, 0]'[t] - 
  x[0, 0][t] + μ*(x[1, 0][t] + x[0, 1][t] - 4*x[0, 0][t] + 
     x[N0, 0][t] + x[0, N0][t]),

x[N0, 0]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[N0, 0][t]^2)*x[N0, 0]'[t] - 
  x[N0, 0][
   t] + μ*(x[0, 0][t] + x[N0, 1][t] - 4*x[N0, 0][t] + 
     x[N0 - 1, 0][t] + x[N0, N0][t]),

x[0, N0]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[0, N0][t]^2)*x[0, N0]'[t] - 
  x[0, N0][
   t] + μ*(x[1, N0][t] + x[0, 0][t] - 4*x[0, N0][t] + 
     x[N0, N0][t] + x[0, N0 - 1][t]),

x[N0, N0]''[t] == ϵ*(1 - x[N0, N0][t]^2)*x[N0, N0]'[t] - 
  x[N0, N0][
   t] + \[Mu]*(x[0, N0][t] + x[N0, 0][t] - 4*x[N0, N0][t] + 
     x[N0 - 1, N0][t] + x[N0, N0 - 1][t]),


    x[0, 0][0] == 1, x[0, 0]'[0] == .5, x[N0/2, N0/2][0] == 0, 
x[N0/2, N0/2]'[0] == 0},
Table[x[i, j]'[0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}, {j, 0, N0}], 
Table[x[i, j][0] == 0, {i, 1, N0/2 - 1}, {j, 0, N0}],
Table[x[i, j]'[0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}, {j, 0, N0}], 
Table[x[i, j][0] == 0, {i, N0/2 + 1, N0}, {j, 0, N0}],
Table[x[N0/2, j]'[0] == 0, {j, 0, N0/2 - 1}], 
Table[x[N0/2, j][0] == 0, {j, 0, N0/2 - 1}],
Table[x[N0/2, j]'[0] == 0, {j, N0/2 + 1, N0}], 
Table[x[N0/2, j][0] == 0, {j, N0/2 + 1, N0}],
Table[x[0, j][0] == 0, {j, 1, N0}], 
Table[x[0, j]'[0] == 0, {j, 1, N0}]]];


moo = NDSolve[crazy, Table[x[i, j], {i, 0, N0}, {j, 0, N0}], {t, 100}]


points = Table[{i, j, x[i, j][t]} /. moo, {i, 0, N0}, {j, 0, 
N0}]

Animate[ListPointPlot3D[points], {t, 0, 100
}, AnimationRate -> 2, AnimationRepetitions -> 2, 
AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: You'll want to start by fixing the syntax errors in your code.

Comment: @CoreyKelly  I don't know how. Hence, my problem.

Comment: Have you read the error messages? They state the problem quite clearly.

Comment: @CoreyKelly  Fixed

Comment: The next problem is that you're trying to plot a function x[i,j] that you haven't defined anywhere.

Comment: @CoreyKelly  Yes I have. It's part of the differential equation, which I numerically solved.

Comment: My mistake! I looked through a tad quickly and missed the `NDSolve[]` entirely

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept Jens' answer, as it quite clearly solves the problem you posed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it work, you first have to flatten the two-dimensional tables in your variable lists. Then since `Animate` holds its arguments unevaluated, one has to inject the instantaneous value of `t` into the `InterpolationFunction`s in some way. One solution is to use a replacement rule with a different variable name `t0` as the time counter for `Animate`:

```
moo = NDSolve[
   crazy,
   Flatten@Table[x[i, j], {i, 0, N0}, {j, 0, N0}], {t, 100}];

points = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, x[i, j][t]} /. moo, {i, 0, N0}, {j, 0, N0}], 2];


Animate[
 ListPointPlot3D[points /. t -> t0, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}, {-10, 10}}], {t0, 0, 100}, 
 AnimationRate -> 2, AnimationRepetitions -> 2, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image: animate]

Here, I also set a fixed `PlotRange` as this makes the movement of the points clearer in the animation.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I need to get myself more adjusted with the flatten command.  Also, why the 2 in "moo"?

How would we connect the dots?

Comment: Why the 2 in `points` (not in `moo`): it's a level specification that tells `Flatten` to collect levels `1` and `2` into a single list, while leaving the three-element lists at level `3` (i.e., the individual  points) in the form of lists. Without level specification, `Flatten` would have turned the lists of  coordinate triplets into a string of individual numbers, unsuitable for the 3D plot. The `Flatten` in `moo` doesn't need the specification because I *want* only a single-level list of function variables.

Comment: Is there any way to connect the dots? I couldn't find anything in the options menu.

Comment: To find a representation you like, you could look into `ListPlot3D` and its options for `Mesh` and `InterpolationOrder`.